# Global DEM and country borders

Tags: esri-geodatabase, dem, spatial-analyst, utm, reclassify

I am trying to split up the world into 2 categories based on elevation (below 2000m and above 2000m) while still including a country identifier.  So in the end, I would like to have 2 types of units (low areas and high areas) for each country in the world, then I will use Spatial Analyst's Zonal Statistics to calculate the mean values of other rasters of interest in my defined areas.  Does anyone have a suggestion for how to do this?

My data:
- 16 DEM tiles for the world
- 1 country borders shapefile

I am struggling with:

1)...working with all the DEM data at once on a global scale because I have been reading the mosaic-king across UTM zones distorts the data.

2)...whether my final units should be in raster form/ file geodatabase grid.  I have heard that I should work in a file geodatabase and forget trying to have my final units be in shapefile form.

I know how to reclassify and have been successful at obtaining a raster with only two categories of elevation for each DEM tiles separately (above and below 2000m).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,
Liz

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, is quite easy. The high level steps can be as follows:

1. Using Raster calculator or the [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000) geoprocessing tool, reclassify the raster into three classes: null for oceans/water, 1 for below 2000 m and 2 for above 2000m.
2. Using [Raster to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000008000000) tool, create a featureclass from this raster.
3. Intersect the output of 2, with your countries shapefile.
4. Once you have the output of 3, use [Summery Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000), to calculate the required statistics. You'll get a table with the required output.